# InputStream from HttpURLConnection: When to disconnect?

Tags: java, inputstream, httpurlconnection

The following constructor method should read an XML from an URL into a XML `Document` object. While it already works, I still doubt it is correct.

```
// Basic constructor method without exception handling
Feed(URL url) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Some User-Agent");

    InputStream inStream = httpcon.getInputStream();

    httpcon.disconnect();

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = builder.parse(inStream);
}
```

**Questions:**

- Shouldn't one first parse the `InputStream` and then close the `HttpURLConnection`?
- Shouldn't there be a `httpcon.connect()` before I try to `get` something from `httpcon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't one first parse the InputStream and then close the HttpURLConnection?

Yes, or rather close the `InputStream.`

> Shouldn't there be a http on.connect() before I try to get something from httpcon?

No. It's implicit in getting the input stream.

The code you posted is incorrect and should not work. The input stream should be read before the disconnect. Actually the disconnect is only necessary if you want o prevent connection pooling.